# About normal states in abstract von Neumann algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, c-star-algebras, hilbert-spaces, von-neumann-algebras, unitary-representations

In the book "Fundamental of the theory of operator algebras" (KAdisong and Ringrose, Vol 2) we have the Corollary 7.1.16

[image]

but this was state only for concrete von Neumann algebras (because they are using SOT and WOT I realice that the algebra is acting on a Hilbert space).

On the other hand we have the result

[image]

where the definition of normal was done in a wide context (for abstract von Neumann algebras)

[image]

So by the corrolary I can assert the following,

**Result 1**: Given $\varphi:N\to M$ a *-isomorphism between two von Neumann algebras acting over its respectives Hilberts spaces and a normal state $\omega$ of $M$, then the state $\omega\circ \varphi$ is a normal state of $N$ (because it must be SOT continuous over the unit ball of $N$).

My question is ¿there exist any similar result for abstract von Neumann algebras? ¿Is the following conjecture true?

**Result 2**: Given $\varphi:N\to M$ a *-isomorphism between two abstract von Neumann algebras and a normal state $\omega$ of $M$, then the state $\omega\circ \varphi$ is a normal state of $N$.

I can not talk about weak or strong topoly here, so I'm stuck, the only topology I know is the one given by the spectral radious of the operators...

Any reference would be fantastic, thanks in advance.

Comment: The strong (resp. weak) operator topology on the unit ball actually coincides with the $\sigma$-strong (resp. $\sigma$-weak) operator topology, which depends only on the abstract von Neumann algebra, not on its representation. Anyway, a $\ast$-isomorphism is an order isomorphism, from which it's not hard to deduce your Result 2.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it was useful

Comment: Try Takesaki's *Theory of Operator Algebras I* or Sakai's *C$^*$-algebras and W$^*$-algebras*. It will help you to know the following convention: "von Neumann algebra" = "weakly closed \*-subalgebra of some $B(\mathcal{H})$", "W$^*$-algebra" = "(abstract) C$^*$-algebra \*-isomorphic to a von Neumann algebra". The various topologies on a W$^*$-algebra $A$ are defined using its *predual* $A_*$.

Comment: Thanks @RobertFurber for the references